# (WPML + woocommerce) product permalinks redirects to shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

This is my permalinks settings screenshot
 [image]

links for product after this settings looks like: example.com/shop/title
but after Upgrading WPML to the latest version something went wrong

when I open product page - wpml return basic shop page for all languages
[image]
with another custom slug (for ex. /item/) its all right

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you contacted WPML support?

Comment: No, i have license but not account in wpml.org